# Is it possible to exclude a line of code from a Visual Studio 2019 code analysis warning (sr0014)?

Tags: database, sql, build, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and Azure SQL Database Instance.

I have a lot of stored procedures that follow the same pattern. A warning is raised on the build for each stored procedure where data loss will occur. I don't want to disable this warning because it is a mistake I can make, I do want to disable it for exactly this scenario. It is obvious to me as a human that it is my intention to lose the time portion of the date.

**Example:**

```
DECLARE @date DATE = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Are `#pragma warning disable` or `#disable warning` (or similar) pre-processor directives available to you? ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/suppress-warnings )

Comment: I found that I am able to selectively right-click the warning and suppress, an ignore message is added to StaticCodeAnalysis.SuppressMessages.xml. I found it by following your link and digging a bit. If you want to add an answer including what i did i can accept it.

Comment: I don't think I can flesh it out properly, but I certainly wouldn't mind (and it is often encouraged) if you answered and accepted your own question with the specifics of what you did

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think it is possible to ignore a line in a T-SQL file**, but it is possible to add a rule applied to that file.

**I did the following:**

1. I navigated to the Error list pane in Visual Studio right-clicked the warning.
2. Selected 'Suppress Static Code Analysis Message'.

Now a file has automatically been added to the project `StaticCodeAnalysis.SuppressMessages.xml` which has the rule to suppress that specific warning on the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StaticCodeAnalysis version="2" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.StaticCodeAnalysis">
  <SuppressedFile FilePath="procs\usp_procName.sql">
    <SuppressedRule Category="Microsoft.Rules.Data" RuleId="SR0007" />
  </SuppressedFile>
</StaticCodeAnalysis>
```